# git - start tracking untracked remote files/directories

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset

Let say I do this:

```
mkdir some_repo
cd some_repo
git init
git touch dummy.txt
git commit -m 'dummy commit'
git remote add -f some_other_remote_repo path/to/.git
git merge --no-ff --no-commit merge remotes/some_other_remote_repo/master
```

No entering `git status` I see something like:

```
new: f1/some.txt
new: f1/some11.txt
new: f2/some2.txt
new: f3/some3.txt
```

So now I only want to add specific directories and their contents. I can do this:

```
git reset f2/
git reset f3/
```

now running `git status`:

```
new: f1/some.txt
new: f1/some11.txt

untracked: f2/some2.txt
untracked: f3/some3.txt
```

So it does what I need and I can commit and remove locally added `f2` and `f3` directories. But what to do if later I decide I now want to track for example `f2` directory and its contents?

No if I run `git merge --no-ff --no-commit merge remotes/some_other_remote_repo/master` again, it will say everything is up to date. So it now ignores those untracked directories. Is their a way to tell git to track specific directories that are in remote only?

Comment: It's worth mentioning here that Git does not track directories per se. Instead, if, at checkout time, Git needs to create some directory `f1` in order to have a file `f1/some.txt`, it simply does so; and when moving from commit X to commit Y, if commit X has `f1/some.txt` and commit Y has nothing at all in `f1` and `f1` becomes empty, Git tends to remove `f1`. (I have seen many corner cases over the years where Git fails to remove empty directories, so you should not count this second behavior too much.)

Comment: @torek yes I understand. I noticed that myself. Though in my case every subdirectory is a module. So the whole directory should be either included or excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Merge the remote branch again. This pulls in the files (again).

## Disclaimer

I consider this very bad practice. After your first merge with deleted files, you have a successful merge in your git history - however, this is clearly not the case.

## Recommendation

Instead, you should create a new branch `some_feature` on top of `remote/master`, delete those files, and then merge `some_feature`.
If you decide you want all files, fully merge `remote/master`.

If the files `some.txt`, `some1.txt`, … are all added in different commits, you may also cherry-pick those commits if they are only a few.

Comment: I actually like your recommendation. It gives more control. I'm gonna try that. Thanks.